# Formated css file becomes single line file in linux

Tags: files

I am working with a large CSS file (about 8000 lines) which is formatted on my local PC (Windows). I use `scp` to copy the file to my Linux server (RHEL7) but when I open the file it has become a single line file.

I would like to have the file formatted in linux so I don't have to copy it to my windows pc, format it, do the changes necessary and the move it back to the server every time I have to do changes.

Do someone know why the file becomes a single line file on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pc/linux issue relates to the different use of line break / CRLF codes in the two systems. [See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos)

You can 'roll your own' solution with a `sed` alias or function but I took the lazy approach by installing `unix2dos` from my repository.

When you import to your pc run

```
dos2unix myfile.css
```

And when exporting for use in dos

```
unix2dos myfile.css
```